# Basic Docopt Example does not work

Tags: python, docopt

So, I'm trying to run `odd_even_example.py` from the [docopt examples git repo](https://github.com/docopt/docopt/blob/master/examples/odd_even_example.py).

No matter what I try to do, or change, the example won't work as expected.

When I:

```
python odd_even_example.py 1 2 3 4
```

I expect to see a dictionary with the command line options or arguments I passed. But instead I just get the `__doc__` string over and over again.

I'm confused because I just copied and ran the file verbatim from the examples repo, and it's straight up broken.

This is the content of the file:

```
"""Usage: odd_even_example.py [-h | --help] (ODD EVEN)...
Example, try:
  odd_even_example.py 1 2 3 4
Options:
  -h, --help
"""
from docopt import docopt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = docopt(__doc__)
    print(arguments)
```

Comment: Can you define what "*Won't work as expected*" means?

Comment: Edited to define what "won't work as expected" means.

Comment: Work for me. Which version of python and what OS you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I think the problem is with whether or not you are entering something for the `(ODD EVEN)` portion of the command. I played with it a bit and still don't understand how exactly that is meant to work, but here is an example that works like you expect. It takes one or more numbers as input, and prints the results to stdout.

```
"""Usage: odd_even_example.py [-h | --help] (NUMBERS)...

Example, try:
  odd_even_example.py 1 2 3 4

Options:
  -h, --help
"""
from docopt import docopt

def is_even(x):
    xIsEven = x%2 == 0
    if xIsEven:
        return 'EVEN'
    else:
        return 'ODD'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = docopt(__doc__) # returns a dictionary
    print(arguments)
    numbers_entered = [int(i) for i in arguments['NUMBERS']]
    answers = [is_even(x) for x in numbers_entered]
    print(answers)
```